# Filter model using many to many field as criteria Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to get all objects that contain the certain many to many field id.i go through a whole lot of SO Post I didn't get it at all. my question is

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 toppings = models.ManyToManyField('Topping')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Topping(models.Model):
  tp_id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

  def __str__(self):
     return self.name
```

i want to get all pizzas objects which has `tp_id = x`.i tried something like this in `view`

```
 filterdObjects =  Pizza.objects.filter(toppings = 1)
```

Comment: That did not work? Normally your queryset should work. Although it might be better to filter with `filterdObjects =  Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__tp_id=1)`

Comment: no.is there any ways to do this?.i think I'm missing something when it comes to m2m field filtering.

Comment: did you try `filterdObjects = Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__tp_id=1)`?

Comment: I tried this before but it will throw an empty query set.

Comment: are you sure (a) there is a `Topping` with `tp_id=1`, and (b) that that topping has some related `Pizza`s.

Answer (score 2):

first you have to filter all Topping objects some how you expect.for example:

```
    all_toppings = Topping.objects.filter(tp_id=1)
```

use filter,even you know that there is just one match because of filtering by the unique field(id). and then you should get your Pizza objects filtered with:

```
    target_pizza = Pizza.objects.filter(topping__in = all_toppings)
```

for filtering by many to many relations you must check the many_to_many filed with a list of objects from target model and for default model managers in django, filter method will return the list data type containing filtered objects.